# BeforeDragOver and BeforeDropOrPaste events VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How exactly do the `BeforeDragOver` and `BeforeDropOrPaste` events work?

I have an Image ActiveX Control on my Workbook and the following code on it:

```
Private Sub Image1_BeforeDragOver(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, ByVal DragState As MSForms.fmDragState, ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)
Range("A1").Value = "test1"
End Sub

Private Sub Image1_BeforeDropOrPaste(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, ByVal Action As MSForms.fmAction, ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)
Range("A1").Value = "test2"
End Sub
```

As I try to drag and drop it, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

## Late to the party, hope it helps someone

#### Credits

Credit to Scottie P (source: [www.vbaexpress.com/...](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-454.html))

Same code can also be found here: [github.com/OfficeDev/VBA-content/...](https://github.com/OfficeDev/VBA-content/blob/master/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/listbox-control-dataobject-object-mousemove-event-startdrag-settext-methods-exam.md)

---

#### Minor Changes

- added `MSForms.` in front of DataObject
- changed `Integer` to `Long`
- declarations on single line

---

Add the following code and two listboxes to a UserForm:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ListBox2_BeforeDragOver(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, ByVal DragState As Long, ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Cancel = True
    Effect = 1
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox2_BeforeDropOrPaste(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, ByVal Action As Long, ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Cancel = True
    Effect = 1
    ListBox2.AddItem Data.GetText
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    Dim MyDataObject As MSForms.DataObject
    If Button = 1 Then
        Set MyDataObject = New MSForms.DataObject
        Dim Effect As Long
        MyDataObject.SetText ListBox1.value
        Effect = MyDataObject.StartDrag
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        ListBox1.AddItem "Choice " & (ListBox1.ListCount + 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```