# Drag and Drop Outlook Attachment into Access Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, drag-and-drop

My boss would like to be able to drag a PDF attachment from an incoming Outlook e-mail into a control on an Access form. The ultimate goal is to save the file in a central folder and display its location with a hyperlink, but first I have to learn how to drag-and-drop the attachment from the email to the Access form.

We'll be distributing the Access front end, but I'm pretty sure I won't be able to do any programming on the Outlook side.

I read that standard VBA controls don't support drag-and-drop, but that ActiveX controls do. I made a form and added a "Microsoft Forms 2.0 TextBox", but when dragged a file from Explorer onto the form, I got the circle-and-slash symbol that meant it wasn't taking it.

I suspect there's something very basic about drag-and-drop that I'm not understanding.

EDIT: Following Mathieu's suggestion, I added a Userform. When I drag a document over it, the BeforeDragOver event triggers. This is the first time anything I had react to a drag-over!

I also tried the code from here: [BeforeDragOver and BeforeDropOrPaste events VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415259/beforedragover-and-beforedroporpaste-events-vba). It works as intended.

Now can someone explain how to adapt that to capturing an external file? I suspect that in this:
`Private Sub Image1_BeforeDropOrPaste(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, ByVal Action As MSForms.fmAction, ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)`

...that the file will be identified in the `ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject` part, but I need to extract its location or something....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569959/vba-drag-and-drop-file-to-user-form-to-get-filename-and-path

Comment: I literally just started reading that. So far I can't find a Treeview control, nor a reference to `Microsoft Windows Common Controls`.

Comment: These would be 32-bit OCX, intended for use with VB6 and 32-bit VBA; there is no 64-bit modern-day equivalent, unfortunately.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Can you help me find MSForm.UserForm?  (I have Rubberduck, but Code Explorer is one of those features I never figured out.)

Comment: Click on the project node, and then use the green + button/dropdown (or right-click and select "add" from the context menu) and select "User Form (.frm)" in the menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KefP.png